# TeX Live Installation Failure on Windows

Tags: texlive, windows

Please help me to resolve this issue... I am using Windows 7 (Enterprise Edition) computer to install Tex Live

While running .exe file, I get an pop up message:

> "To unpack an then run install-tl-windows.bat or
>   instal-tl-advanced.bat"

.

Upon downloading zip and unpacking it, I followed above message instructions, however there is nothing processing.

It would be great help to have this resolved. Looking for your valuable responses.

Thank you,
Bhavin Patel

Comment: Did you run from `tug.org` file `install-tl-windows.exe` or `install-tl.zip`? If you run first, then gui window should run and installation goes as any installation on windows.